# Return an interface in PHP?

Tags: php, interface

Is it possible to return an interface from a function?  Example:

```
interface DBInterface {
  public function getDB();
  [...]
}

class Bar {

  public function defineDBObject($name){
    return DBInterface;
  }
}
```

I doubt it, but I have a client who likes to write involved spec docs that are calling for it.  I want to make sure that it is, in fact, impossible.

Comment: AFAIK Interfaces can't have an instance.

Comment: The closest you can get is to return an object that implements that interface - otherwise, no.

Comment: Does he intend to return the actual interface definition, or an object that implements the interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. You can only return objects or primitives. Classes and interfaces are not objects in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You can return a [`ReflectionClass`](http://ar.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php) instance that represents the interface. Returning the interface directly is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return an interface. You can only return an object. The object that you return can implement a particular interface - hence having those methods implemented.

It is a mechanism that is *borrowed* from Java to get over the diamond problem.